# How to expect the date to contain another date in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, bdd

This would be silliest question which I am asking here. I was going through Cypress automation and was working on one of the scenario.

I wanted to verify whether the date is matching or containing the date or not.

System date - `11/30/2021 06:18:33 PM` and derived application date - `11/30/2021 6:18:38`

How can I match and assert this using Cypress?

```
expect('11/30/2021 06:18:33 PM').to.have.string('11/30/2021 6:18:38');
```

I am getting below error :-

```
AssertionError

expected '11/30/2021 06:18:33 PM' to contain '11/30/2021 6:18:38'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to.include`, something like:

```js
expect('11/30/2021 06:18:33 PM').to.include('11/30/2021 06:18:33')
```

Or if you just want to match the dates, you can do something like this. Using `split` we are extracting just the date and asserting it.

```js
expect('11/30/2021 06:18:33 PM'.split(' ')[0]).to.equal(
  '11/30/2021 06:18:33'.split(' ')[0]
)
```

Comment: I am still getting error  - AssertionError
expected '11/30/2021 07:05:53 PM' to include '11/30/2021 7:5:57'

Comment: There are two differences one in the `11/30/2021 6:18:38` from the first date. The time in the main date is `06` and the second is `33`. So you have to change those. Updated my answer.